# Any way to have pythod based FTDI Server

Tags: python, ftdi

I am using FTDI driver (pyftdi) to talk to FT4232H based FTDI device connected through USB to PC and on the other side device is connected another HW DUT.

There is GUI which invokes pyftdi driver to connect to the DUT from PC and I can control the DUT through GUI.

Now, I have another requirement where I want to run few standalone scripts in parallel on the same DUT to which GUI is connected. When this script tries to establish a serial connection, it fails with below error messages:

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyftdi\i2c.py", line 512, in configure
    frequency = self._ftdi.open_mpsse_from_url(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 543, in open_mpsse_from_url
    debug=debug)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 662, in open_mpsse_from_device
    frequency = self._set_frequency(frequency)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 1929, in _set_frequency
    self.write_data(cmd)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 1507, in write_data
    raise FtdiError('UsbError: %s' % str(ex))
pyftdi.ftdi.FtdiError: UsbError: [Errno None] b'libusb0-dll:err [claim_interface] could not claim interface 0, win error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.\r\n'
```

Is it possible to create FTDI server kind of interface which would serve both the connections?

The way serial connections are being made is through pyftdi

```
self.port = pyftdi.serialext.serial_for_url(self.name,
                                                    baudrate=self.baudRate,
                                                    timeout=self.timeout,
                                                    bytesize=8,
                                                    stopbits=1,
                                                    parity='N',
                                                    xonxoff=False,
                                                    rtscts=False)
```

Comment: If you can modify the GUI app, you could add a [TCP to serial bridge](https://github.com/marcelomd/mux_serial) to it. Otherwise you'll need a mux server and to connect both, the gui and the app to virtual ports as [it's shown here](http://www.eluaproject.net/doc/v0.9/en_building_win.html). _Serial Port Multiplexing_ is the keyword you're looking for

Comment: What protocol do you use to communicate with the DUT? Do you need to "share" the same port or do you want to actually use multiple ports of th FTDI in separate application? Maybe the VCP driver would be an option in this case.

Comment: I want to use the same port across GUI & Standalone App/script

Comment: @xvan, thank you for pointers. Will take a look at [mux_serial](https://github.com/marcelomd/mux_serial) solution

Comment: @xvan, the mux_serial solution seems to be for linux. As the select module doesn't work on windows. you have any other suggestions for windows?

Comment: you could release the handle for the meantime or pass the traffic from the scripts over the gui.

Comment: @ChristianB. my connectivity to the hw module is established using pyftdi serial driver instance (As shown in the actual code above). So, how do i release the handle to other? Any suggestions/snippet?

Comment: Normally there is a close methode for ports. Regarding the "passing the traffic" you need to come up with a suitable solution as we dont know your exact requirements. You can look for "inter process communication". Normally one can use pipes/queues for that to pass stuff between processes and then pass this to the port again.

Comment: @ChristianB. Thanks for the pointers. Will go through IPC.